# If my team has multiple feature branches, we then need multiple QA environments?

Tags: tfs

If we have 3 feature branches being developing in parallel, this means by definition we need 3 QA environments correct?

Otherwise people will be overwriting each other's code.

The only other way would be to have another branch that we pushed (all 3 feature branches) to before pushing to QA.

Comment: It depends, what is your release schedule for the 3 features? What is the QA schedule?

Comment: Well, adding some context might help.  Is it a web environment, a server batch process, is it database dependent, can they share a database, are there are other resources that would be shared, or couldn't be shared?

Comment: perhaps this should move to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Branching strategy is a big topic, but here are some links that I've found useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx

http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com

http://tfsbranchingguideii.codeplex.com/releases/view/20785

http://www.ericsink.com/scm/scm_branches.html

Not sure sure what you mean by a "QA environment", but typically QA would work off a single `Main` branch of "stable" features. Releases would branch off `Main`. Your "feature" branches, if any, would branch off a different `Development` branch (also branched off `Main`) with a potentially looser check in policy. `Development` would be used for continuous integration and build verification testing. However, I get the sense that "feature branches" can really be done as shelvesets of `Development` instead of requiring a branch.

Comment: QA on main is a concept that I still cannot grasp. Lets say there are three features A,B,C merged to main and QA passes A and C while B failed and it failed many times (due to various reasons) at the end of sprint A and C are ready to go but cannot because B is blocking them. How do you fix this ?

Comment: I think of this way: QA is responsible for ensuring that released software meets a certain minimum standard for your organization (ie when to branch from Main to Release), or becomes a "Release Candidate" and gets a release number and branch of its own. Development are responsible for making sure features are "Done". Depending upon what you mean by "B failed", it means either the feature is not actually "Done" (and probably shouldn't have been merged into Main), or QA is not comfortable with releasing due to some non-functional requirement (performance, security, etc).

Comment: Either way, if you're tying the end of a sprint to an actual release branch, you're going to have to back B out - either it gets reverted from Main or it somehow gets "turned off" in the release.

Comment: backing out with a simple revert is a problem when C is dependent on B. The only solution that I can think of is using feature flags and using them extensively. It is very difficult (almost impossible) to manage a "daily release" fluid system without utilizing feature flags and that is what I am trying to educate my team on.